# Regular Expression Help for Date Validation - dd/mm/yyyy - PHP

Tags: php, regex, datetime, date, preg-match

Can someone show me the error of my ways when it comes to this regular expression:

```
if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$/", $_POST["date"]) === 0) {
   echo 'error';
}
```

Basically I want this to display an error message each time - unless the format is correct (dd/mm/yyyy).

What am I doing wrong with the above?

Many thanks for any pointers.

**-- updated regex above shortly after posting - apologies for inconvenience --**

Comment: Use an online regexp tester ex. http://www.regexpal.com/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you should escape the slashes `/^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}$/`

Comment: Many thanks for this. I will green tick shortly :)

Comment: thank you. this work for me also. Voted you up.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the slash since you are using it as regex delimiter

```
/^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}$/
```

or use different regex delimiters

```
#^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$#
```

Comment: Fantastic. That now works perfectly. Silly me :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this one:

```
([0-2]\d|3[0-1])\/(0\d|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}
```

if you want to differentiate between dates and months, but also validate only 2 centuries.

Comment: And if you need to capture `^([0-2]\d|3[0-1])\/(0\d|1[0-2])\/((?:19|20)\d{2})$` and also have added begining and ending anchors. Also there is a bug that dates with zero day and month will work '00/00/1999'.

Answer (score 2):

I use this for checking dates

```
private function validate_date( $date, $empty_allowed = true ) {

    if ( empty( $date ) ) {
        return $empty_allowed;
    }

    if ( ! strpos( $date, '/' ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( substr_count( $date, '/' ) !== 2 ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( preg_match( '/(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(2[0-9][0-9][0-9]|1[6-9][0-9][0-9])/', $date ) !== 1 ) {
        return false;
    }

    $split = explode( '/', $date );

    return checkdate( $split[1], $split[0], $split[2] );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to solve your problem.

```
^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$
```

Output looks Like=> `31/12/2019`

[Test Demo](https://www.regextester.com/99555)