# Regex - Date format along with having max value set

Tags: php, regex, date

I'm using the regex from this question [Regular Expression Help for Date Validation - dd/mm/yyyy - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293483/regular-expression-help-for-date-validation-dd-mm-yyyy-php) from validating the date format

```
/^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}$/
```

However I'd also like to ensure that the date is in this specific format `DD/MM/YYYY` and NOT as `MM/DD/YYYY`, so I was wondering whether there's a way to "tell" my regex that this part

`\/[0-9]{1,2}\/`

should also have a value up to 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/(0[1-9])|(1[0-2])/
```